# Android NDK build with ANT script

Tags: android, ant, build, android-ndk

Can we use the ANT script for Android NDK builds ?
If Yes how?
And if no, then why Not ?

I don't have any idea about it

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Call `ndk-build` from your `-pre-build` target, like this:

```
<target name="-pre-build">
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build" failonerror="true"/>
</target>

<target name="clean" depends="android_rules.clean">
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="clean"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Then you can set `ndk.dir` to point at the NDK directory from your `local.properties` file, or set it on the command line. I do this:

```
ant -Dsdk.dir=/home/dg/apps/android-sdk-linux_x86-r11/ -Dndk.dir=/home/dg/apps/android-ndk-r6b release
```

Now running ant will build your native code automatically. Plus, running 'ant clean' will clean your native code.

**Updated:** Added `failonerror="true"` to the `<exec>` tasks --- this causes ant to abort if the make fails. Without it it'll just go right ahead and generate an APK with an invalid binary in it. Not good!

Comment: Thanks

Actually done with it, but forget to edit here

what I did is this
<target name="n"><echo message="Starting Android NDK build step..." />       <!-- Build JNI code and create shared object loaded by app -->
              <exec executable="sh" failonerror="yes" >
                  <arg value="${env.ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/ndk-build" />
                  <arg value="V=1" />
              </exec>
         <echo message="...finished Android NDK build step." /></target>

Comment: On windows, you have to use `sh` as the executable, and the ndk-build script as the first argument.

Comment: In what file do those <target> directives go?  isn't the build.xml file generated by the android tool?, so changes would be destroyed if you have to update the project.

Comment: I *believe* that the automatic build.xml generator will attempt to merge around your own customisations when updating the project, but I don't use it so I can't tell you for sure.

Comment: You should put this custom build step in custom_rules.xml as it is included in to the autogenerated build.xml but not modified.

Comment: On windows use: `ndk-build.cmd` instead of `ndk-build`

Comment: What's the `release` suffix for?

Comment: It tells ant to build the target called `release`, which (IIRC) is part of the standard Android rules to generate a release-mode apk file.

Answer (score 9):

here is what to add to your build.xml as others stated:

```
<target name="-pre-build">
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build" failonerror="true"/>
</target>

<target name="clean" depends="android_rules.clean">
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="clean"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

define the ndk.dir in local.properties file:
ndk.dir=C:\EclipseWorkspace\android-ndk-r8d

The situation i wanted to mention after doing this you get an error "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" while running ANT against this target override.  For me i had to upgrade to NDK R8d and also update the following line so that it fetches ndk-build.cmd (this version of ndk can run on windows and via cygwin:

exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.**cmd**" failonerror="true"

Comment: thanks j2emanue for helping out. But answer is given and accepted already :)

Comment: Hopefully this can help others was the intention, thanks though.

Comment: the '.cmd' part is important on windows

Comment: for windows, [...executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build"...] should be, [...executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build.cmd"...] as per the comment by @Hoang Tran

Comment: Trying to use the Visual Studio installation of ant to build APK from C++ source, running ccmd: