# Android native library project with native code

Tags: android, pdf

I Just download [this project](https://code.google.com/p/vudroid/) and I want to make it be a Android Library project. To use it in others Android applications. But it's not so easy as I think. When I put it in other Android app I got a null pointer excecption when I use it. I think the problem is because this project has some native codes - JNI and I have todo some configuration, but I don't know what configuration.  Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Post the full stack trace for the `NullPointerException`. Also, what did you do to make it an Android Library project? What's the code you used that caused the `NullPointerException`? This question is lacking many important relevant details.

Comment: The null pointer doesn't matter. If I put my code in the project library (VUDroid)  it works fine.There's no problem with the code. My problem is how to configure VUDroid to became a Android library project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what steps you should do without more details like what build system you are using (ant, Eclipse, Intellij, maven, etc), and I think the request of the full stack trace was correct, but just in general terms you need to make sure the code in vudroid's jni dir is being build with the Android NDK which you can find here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Also ensure that the ARM object files produced by the NDK are packaged correctly by whatever build system you are using.

Take a look at the answer here for an example using ant:

[Android NDK build with ANT script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432449/android-ndk-build-with-ant-script)